# Submit DocuSign PowerForms

Tags: docusignapi

I need to create a page with powerform fields and submit these values ​​via api. Is there such a possibility? Note: I don't want to integrate powerform on my website, I would like to take these fields and submit them via api.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, please, check/accept the best answer to each of your questions. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a powerform programmatically, including setting its tab (field) values. To do so make a GET or POST HTTP call to DocuSign from the `browser`. The browser will then be redirected to the powerform user experience for the signer to view and sign the resulting envelope.

See my [Programming PowerForms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BKfyDSMoSE) video for all the details.